# How to find the average of values in a .txt file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I need to find the minimum, maximum, and average of values given in a .txt file. I've been able to find the minimum and maximum values but I'm struggling with finding the average of values. I haven't wrote any coding for determining the average as I have no clue where to start. My current code is:

```
def summaryStats():
    filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
    file = open(filename)
    data = file.readlines()
    data = data[0:]
    print("The minimum value is " + min(data))
    print("The maximum value is " + max(data))
```

I need to be able to return the average of these values. As of now the .txt document has the following values:

```
893
255
504
```

I'm struggling on being able to find the average of these because every way I try to find the sum my result is 0.

Thanks
(sorry I'm just learning to work with files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should convert the data retrived from file to integers first, because your data list contains strings not numbers. And after the conversion to integers average can be found easily:

Why conversion to int is required?

```
>>> '2' > '10'  #strings are compared lexicographically
True
```

**Code:**

```
def summaryStats():
    filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = [int(line) for line in f]

    print("The minimum value is ", min(data))
    print("The maximum value is ", max(data))
    print("The average value is ", sum(data)/len(data))
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a file name: abc1
The minimum value is  255
The maximum value is  893
The average value is  550.6666666666666
```

Comment: Probably the function should just receive the name of a file, and the calling code should figure out how to receive the file name from the user. A command-line argument is often more user friendly than interactive input, somewhat paradoxically.

Comment: @tripleee True, I'd do something similar. :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use `numpy` it takes a couple of instructions. You can import a txt file into a numpy array and then use the built-in function to perform the operations you want:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
>>> np.average(data)
 550.666666667
>>> np.max(data)
 893.0
>>> np.min(data)
 255.0
```

Comment: That's potentially a *lot* of overhead for what might be very simple requirements. I wouldn't recommend numpy without knowing more about the needs.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not aware of the numpy function, I haven't come across that yet.

Comment: Numpy is a very popular third-party library, so very likely worth at least a quick review if you want to do numeric things in Python. To just read in and divide a list of numbers, it's massive overkill; but if you want to do more, it might very well be worth the additional learning curve.